# c language temperature converter : fahrenheit to celcius

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{
   float fahrenheit;
   int celcius;

   celcius=(fahrenheit-32)*(5.0/9.0);

   printf("Enter your fahrenheit temperature : ");

   scanf("%f",&fahrenheit);

   printf("Your fahrenheit temperature in celcius is :%d\n",celcius);
}
```

Comment: Use a `c` tag, not a `c#` tag

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this:

```
celcius=(ferenheit-32)*(5.0/9.0);
```

Does not mean that the value of `celcius` will always be `(ferenheit-32)*(5.0/9.0)`, anytime that `ferenheit` changes.  What is does mean is that it sets `celcius` to `(ferenheit-32)*(5.0/9.0)` **at the time the statement is encountered**.  Since `ferenheit` doesn't have value yet when this statement runs, the value of `celcius` is indeterminate.

You need to first read in the value of `ferenheit`, *then* calculate `celcius` based on that:

```
printf("Enter your ferenheit temperature : ");
scanf("%f",&ferenheit);             // first read
celcius=(ferenheit-32)*(5.0/9.0);   // then calculate
printf("Your ferenheit temperature in celcius is :%d\n",celcius);
```

Also, they're spelled "celsius" and "fahrenheit".